# Ellipse formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

In the video https://youtu.be/eI4an8aSsgw?t=16354 the professor says that the following equation
$$\sqrt{(x+c)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=2a$$
simplifies to
$$
(a^2-c^2)x^2+a^2y^2=a^2(a^2-c^2)
$$
I don't get it. I need someone who can explain it step by step

Comment: Hint: call $U,V$ the two square roots. Do $(U+V)^2=4a^2$ then $(2UV)^2=(4a^2-U^2-V^2)^2$ you get the expression proposed after expansion many terms cancel out.

Comment: that's kinda helpful but why do you square it a second time?

Comment: Because the double product $2UV$ still has square roots. The aim is to get rid of them, so you square the sum once, isolate the remaining roots on one side and square again.

Comment: hmm ok but somehow i got still a different answer...

Comment: I have got $$2x+2y=2a^2-x^2-c^2-y^2$$

Comment: The sad, unimaginative approach - i.e., the one I would have chosen - is to isolate one square root (the first, say): subtract the other (the second, say) on both sides of the equal sign. Then square both sides. Cancel terms that can be canceled. There will remain  a square root - but only one. Isolate the square root (i.e., add/subtract to move everything else to the other side), and square again.  Yuck, you say; agreed, but no more square roots. The slogan here is one step at a time: isolate a square root, so that squaring gets rid  of it, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\sqrt{(x+c)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=2a=\sqrt{P}+\sqrt{Q}~~~(1)$$
$$\implies P-Q=4cx \implies \sqrt{P}-\sqrt{Q}=2cx/a~~~(2)$$
Adding (1) and (2) get
$$\sqrt{P}=xc/a+a \implies (x+c)^2+y^2=(cx/a+a)^2 \implies (1-c^2/a^2)x^2+y^2=a^2-c^2$$
$$\implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{(1-c^2/a^2)}=1$$
Let $c=ae$, then we get ellips as
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$$

Comment: that's not the path the prof chose in the video... I think

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $\begin{cases}U=\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}\\V=\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\end{cases}\quad$ and we start from $U+V=2a$

Squaring we get $\quad U^2+2UV+V^2=4a^2$

$U^2+V^2=(x+c)^2+y^2+(x-c)^2+y^2=2(x^2+y^2+c^2)$

Now we'll divide by $2$ and put the roots on one side and square again:

$$U^2V^2=(2a^2-\tfrac 12(U^2+V^2))^2$$
$\begin{align}U^2V^2
&=((x+c)^2+y^2)((x-c)^2+y^2)\\
&=((x+c)^2+(x-c)^2)y^2+(x+c)^2(x-c)^2+y^4\\
&=(2x^2+2c^2)y^2+(x^2-c^2)^2+y^4\\
\require{cancel}&=\cancel{2x^2y^2}+\cancel{2c^2y^2}+\cancel{x^4}-2c^2x^2+\cancel{c^4}+\cancel{y^4}
\end{align}$

It is equal to:

$(2a^2-x^2-y^2-c^2)^2
\require{cancel}=4a^4+\cancel{x^4}+\cancel{y^4}+\cancel{c^4}-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2+\cancel{2x^2y^2}+2x^2c^2+\cancel{2y^2c^2}$

Gathering remaining terms:

$-2x^2c^2=4a^4-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2+2x^2c^2\iff 4\Big(a^4-a^2x^2-a^2y^2-a^2c^2+x^2c^2\Big)=0$

$$(-a^2+c^2)x^2-a^2y^2+a^2(a^2-c^2)=0$$

Which is the desired expression.